# Linux equivalent of Solaris walkcontext

Tags: c++, linux, solaris

What's the Linux equivalent of Solaris walkcontext? 
Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0213/6m6ne38fv/index.html
On Linux, I am getting error as:

```
error: walkcontext was not declared in this scope
```

when I use:   `walkcontext(&uc, walk_callback, &ctx);`

Comment: There's no such *Linux* specific function, but there are special compiler (GCC or Clang) functions that can be used to get the function call stack. If you search a little you should be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct Linux equivalent of Solaris `walkcontext()`. As stated in comment there are compiler/platform specific methods like libunwind and _Unwind_Backtrace.

Some of those are nicely wrapped in ISC's bind `backtrace.c` source (for obtaining backtrace of a running process):

https://source.isc.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=bind9.git;a=blob;f=lib/isc/backtrace.c;h=1f7cd570bd28dffebb20654a692f3ee5e8079f95;hb=HEAD